# ng-bind span not updated on changing the object's property

Tags: angularjs

In the following code, i change the object's property on clicking the 'tab' element, but the corresponding ngbind span is not getting updated. Do i have to call some function to update the view?

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="splx">
  ...
  <body ng-controller="Application">
    <span ng-bind="obj.val"></span>
    <tabpanel selector="obj">
      <div tab value="junk">junk</div>
      <div tab value="super">super</div>
    </tabpanel>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var cf = angular.module('splx', []);

function Application($scope) {
  $scope.obj = {val: "something"};
}

cf.directive('tabpanel', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      selector: '='
    },
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {}]
  };
});

cf.directive('tab', function() {
  return {
    require: '^tabpanel',
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('click', function() {
        scope.$parent.selector.val = "newthing";
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: You have some answers and all, but I'm heavily doubting your need for these directives at all. Generally, and need for $scope.apply() implies a less than ideal approach. That should only be needed when using non-angular code (like a 3rd party library operating outside of angular's control. Are you sure you can't accomplish what you need without directives at all? I made you this example of tabs only using databinding between the view and controller. Very easy. http://jsbin.com/OmUhIVi/1/edit You can do a lot more complicated things than that with just databinding.

Comment: thanks a lot @m59, Its just a small snippet i pasted here. Actually your tab component also seems like a simpler way of doing this. I'll give a try.

Comment: It's the point of the controller to bind data to the view like that. You could say that $scope is a data representation of the view. Something like `$scope.selectedTab` isn't about dom manipulation, but rather view presentation based on data (what is selected), so a special directive isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cf.directive('tab', function() {
  return {
    require: '^tabpanel',
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('click', function() {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          scope.$parent.selector.val = "newthing";
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

That works for me. Just missing a little scope.$apply in there.

Might want to have a look at https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma if you find yourself using/having trouble with '$apply already in progress'.

If you want to change the value to what you clicked on, I'd do something like this:

```
scope.$parent.selector.val = attrs.tab;
```

As opposed to:

```
scope.$parent.selector.val = "newthing";
```

And then you can change your markup to look like this:

```
<tabpanel selector="obj">
  <div tab="junk">junk</div>
  <div tab="super">super</div>
</tabpanel>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

First problem: you are not binding your controller to your app.
You need `cf.controller('Application', Application);`.
Also you need `ng-controller="Application"` in HTML on a parent of that `span` and the `tabpanel` directive.

Second problem: after changing that scope variable in your `click` event you need to
`scope.$apply()` to let Angular know something changed and it needs to `$digest` it.

You can check out my version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xLpHG/).